# Which vector library to use for GUI developent in python?

Tags: python, gui, svg

I'm looking for some kind of vector library similar to the (old) RaphaelJS (http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/) that can be used to implement GUIs.

RaphaelJS uses SVG to create vector shapes in a web browser. These shapes can be modified by changing properties and allow event handlers to act on clicks and such things. I'm wondering if there's something similar, ideally cross-platform, maybe even available on android, but at least for Python? It should be easy to use and use hardware acceleration. (Maybe there's even a GUI builder.) Do you know of some library like that? Which one could I use? I'm sure there are some available, I just couldn't figure out which one is usable and not a dead end as projects seem to die quite regularly in the OS world. Thanks a lot for your answer!